# Diagonalizable matrices of finite odd order are the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to prove that if $A^n = I$ for some odd $n \geq 1$, and $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A=I$. So if $A$ is diagonalizable, there exists $PAP^{-1}=D$ and also $PA^mP^{-1}=I$. To prove $A=I$, we need $D=I$ but how does it work?

Comment: Note $I=P A^m P^{-1}=(PAP^{-1})^m =D^m $.

Answer (score 1):

This is false (*assuming you mean diagonalizable over the complex numbers*).

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} \zeta&0&0\\0&\zeta&0\\0&0&\zeta\end{bmatrix}$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity with $n$ odd.

Then $A$ is trivially diagonalizable (as it is diagonal in the first place) and $A^n = I$ yet $A\neq I$

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means diagonalizability over the reals, in which case it's true.

Answer (score 1):

As JMoravitz noticed, it is false over the complex numbers. Let's assume then that we're talking about reals.

The polynomial $P(X) = X^n - 1$ annihilates $A$, so the eigenvalues of $A$ are roots of $P(X)$, ie are 1 (because $n$ is odd). As $A$ is diagonalizable, $D = 1$, and $A = 1$ follows.